# how can we set/change the default shape directory

Tags: tableau-api

My question is around, how can we set/change the default shape directory.

I am currently working on to set an org structure for a company. The scenario is that people keep joining the company and I want Tableau to pick a default image in the org structure instead of default available shapes (circle, square, plus, etc).

[image]

You can see the snapshot of the dashboard, where I do not have the image for resource3 and Tableau picked + automatically. P.S.: the above snapshot is sanitized and I used gender icons for the image instead.

Please help me figure out either, how to add an image as default in the default folder and location of the default folder? or how can I set a different folder as default?

This is the image that I want to set as default. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: cant see image, please provide the same

Comment: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/viewparts_marks_markproperties_shape.html